# The NOW() function with code igniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I want to post the `now()` function in my mysqli 
but there is no output. When I use the time `('NOW()')` I get `838:59:59`.

```
<?php
public function ajax_add()
{
    $this->_validate();
    $data = array(
        'datum' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'firma' => $this->input->post('firma'),
        'naam' => $this->input->post('naam'),
        'telefoonnummer' => $this->input->post('telefoonnummer'),
        'opdrachtgever' => $this->input->post('opdrachtgever'),
        'werkzaamheden' => $this->input->post('werkzaamheden'),
        'aangemeld' => $this->input->post('aangemeld'),
        'pasnummer' => $this->input->post('pasnummer'),
        'aangemeld' => time('NOW()')
        );
    $insert = $this->person->save($data);
}
?>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: want to save date and time?

Comment: @S.Spieker The OP has it mixed up, it's nothing to do with jQuery at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `aangemeld` from the `$data` array and set it like this:

`$this->db->set('aangemeld', 'NOW()', FALSE);`

Then call your `save()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess here is the problem with your this line

> 'aangemeld' => time('NOW()')

time() method doesn't have any parameters.

If you want to pass now as an unix timestamp you should use just

> time()

If you want you can pass like this:

> date("d/m/Y H:i:s");

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

instead of

```
'aangemeld' => time('NOW()')
```

For current timestamp

`time()` dont have parameters.